# preventing sharing in any frame

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013

I follow this code to add share content in my windows 8 app (C#).
I have done it corectly in Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012. But It's not the same when I try with  Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013. 
The problem is When I navigate to the frame after and then navigate to the frame before , It didn't generate any error. Finally, all the frame can be shared at anytime.

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dataTransfer = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dataTransfer.DataRequested += dataTransfer_DataRequested;

    }


    void dataTransfer_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataRequest request = args.Request;
        request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Text Example";
        request.Data.Properties.Description = "A demonstration that shows how to share text.";
        request.Data.SetText("Hello World!");
    }

    DataTransferManager dataTransfer;
```

I had added the following code to prohibit the ability to share in other page. But It has no change at all.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            dataTransfer.DataRequested -= dataTransfer_DataRequested; 
        }
```

Can we prohibit the ability to share in another page that we do not want to share? (with visual 2013 and Windows 8.1)